# How to set a fixed size for the items of a QListView

Tags: qt, grid, size, qlistview, qabstractitemmodel

I have `QListView` in icon mode and I am setting a `QIdentityProxyModel` on it. The problem is that my items are not placed in an order like being on a grid and I guess that the problem is that they have different widths, due to the different size of their names.

How can I fix this issue? Is there any solution for `QListView` items similar to `setSizeHint()` of `QListWidgetItem`?

```
m_itemsModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
m_iconProxy = new IconProxy(this);
m_iconProxy->setSourceModel(m_itemsModel);
ui.listView->setModel(m_iconProxy);
ui.listView->setUniformItemSizes(true);
```

And as I have mentioned in my comment below, I have set `iconSize` to 64x64.
Furthermore, my `QIdentityProxyModel` has overridden the method `data` to return an empty `QIcon()` or a custom thumbnail or the operating system's icon.

And I get this (wrong):

[image]

instead of this (correct):

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the [`uniformItemSizes`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#uniformItemSizes-prop) property.

Comment: @G.M. : Yes that almost solves my problem. But maybe creates another one. When I list one directory i get trimmed icons (with small height). When I go back and forward the icon size is correct.
I am setting `setIconSize(64, 64)` on `QListView`, but in the first listing it ignores the height. 
I am wondering how my `QListView` gets its size when i enable the property `uniformItemSizes`

Comment: Can't really diagnose the issue any further without more info and/or code.  See if you can put together an [`mcve`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @G.M. : sure! I edited my post. Please have a look.

Comment: Based on what you've shown I've been unable to reproduce the issues your seeing.  I can only surmise that the problem lies with the `IconProxy` class.  Try removing that -- or replacing it with a plain old `QIdentityProxyModel` -- to see if that has any effect.

Comment: Hi! How did you solve the problem, I also have the same problem with items height which every item has a different height.